# How to add labels to a violin plot using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, violin-plot

I'm trying to label a violin plot with Seaborn using:

`ax = sns.violinplot(x='distance', y='Length', data=class_A, scale= 'count')`

[sns.violinplot without hue set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEFX5.png)

When I add `hue='population'`, which is what I'd like to label each violin plot with, I lose my KDE and it only shows the boxplot.

[With Hue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHX5W.png)

Any idea why this is happening? Any suggestions to label each violinplot by a column?

Comment: Post a sample of your dataframe

Comment: Looks like you don't need hue. Is each distance mapped to exactly one population? Its trying to plot all 20 population violins for each distance and smashing them together.

Comment: You could try and make a custom x-axis label of population with distance together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your data has a one-to-one mapping from `distance` to `population`. When you add in `hue`, `seaborn` is trying to make a violin plot for each distance for each `population`. This would be about 400 violin plots based on your data. The problem is that only 20 of these combinations have any data because of the one to one mapping. Thus, there is no point in using `hue`.

You can however, change the x labels in the plot to show both the distance and the population with something like this.

```
df_labels = class_A[['distance', 'population']].sort_values('distance').drop_duplicates()
new_labels = df_labels.distance + ' \n' + df_labels.population
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, however, since the labels are a combination of distance and text I made  a slight change to..

`new_labels = df_labels.distance.astype(str) + ' \n' + df_labels.population`